# angular 6 compilation process flow and role of browser in compilation of angular app

Tags: angular, compiler-construction, jit, aot

I have done a lot of research on angular compilation process but could not clear my doubts.what is difference between aot and jit in angular compilation?
Does AOT convert our html into javascript or typescript?
is there any difference between typescript compiler and angular compiler?
what is the flow of compilation process and what is the role of browser in this process?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Comment: yes i read it and also watched videos on youtube.But it is creating confusion.

Comment: I am not able to understand that how aot converts html into typescript and browser receives javascript file

Comment: You could create a very simple app, build it for production, and take a look at the result.